# peewee field default type and DateTimeField

Tags: python, peewee

I have created model class inherititng form `peewee.Model`

```
import peewee

class Example(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.IntField(primary_key=True)
    text = peewee.charField(default="waiting")
    dt = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

but when I insert new value for just only id field to the `example` table I do not get the default  `text` value as "waiting" and date_added also comes out to be `0000-00-00 00:00:00` isntead of current date time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields need to be members of the class:

```
class Example(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.IntField(primary_key=True)
    text = peewee.CharField(default="waiting")
    dt = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Additionally, you want the default value to be a callable for the datetime...otherwise it will evaluate datetime.datetime.now() at the time the module is loaded and never re-evaluate it.

Comment: sorry that is just a typo because I hand typed the code from phone, fields are part of the class

Comment: Did this resolve the issue? In short, you should be passing python datetime objects to the `dt` field.